# Can't create instance of an async task by `cls.newInstance()`?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, instantiation

The android code is simple:

```
public void createNewTask(View v) {
    try {
        MyTask task = MyTask.class.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return null;  
    }
}
```

But when invoking `createNewTask` method, it will throw an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.MyActivity$MyTask
    at com.example.MyActivity.createNewTask(MyActivity.java:214)
    ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.MyActivity$MyTask
    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1440)
    at com.example.MyActivity.createNewTask(MyActivity.java:211)
```

But if I choose another class, e.g.

```
MyActivity task = MyActivity.class.newInstance();
```

Everything will be fine.

Where is wrong in my code? I tested it in an android phone with android 2.3.6.

Comment: Just for curiosity, why don't you do MyTask task = new MyTask();

Comment: did you try adding a default constructor in your `MyTask` class?

Comment: Because I want to create a helper method which can check the task's state and create one if necessary. The real code is more complex than the sample in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found two ways to solve this problem:

```
public static class MyTask {
}
```

or

```
private static class MyTask {
    public MyTask(){}
}
```

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29):

> InstantiationException - if this Class represents an abstract class,
>   an interface, an array class, a primitive type, or void; or if the
>   class has no nullary constructor; or if the instantiation fails for
>   some other reason.

Try adding nullary constructor to your class:

```
public MyTask() {}
```

**EDIT**

According to [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html):

> Class.newInstance() requires that the constructor be **visible**;
>   Constructor.newInstance() may invoke private constructors under
>   certain circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose ,the reason is `AsyncTask` is abstract class, but `Activity` not.

And private class cannot be instantiate like you do

Comment: What I am passing is a subclass of `AsyncTask`, not `AsyncTask` itself.

Comment: yes, `MyTask` is not an *abstract* class. it must be something else